# Arkit corelocation Altitude (y, Height)

Tags: swift, core-location, arkit

playing around with ARkit for the first time to place real world objects. getting the objects to go in at x,z (log/lat) seems to work ok but struggling with y (height) of objects. anyone got any example of height data being used?

any examples would help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Plz update with what you have done and where the problem lies

Answer (score 2):

[image]

y-axis in the positive will make the node go upwards (units in metres).

so if I want to position my node.... 1 metre in front of the camera and 10 metres high. You would set the position of the node below.

SCNVector3(x:float, y:float, z:float)

node.position = SCNVector3(0,10,-1)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Altitude is above sea level in meters. So if your location has altitude of 170m and you want your object to be floating in 10m, then you want to put altitude of 180.